# Mongoose Error when Populating ('model' is not a function)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**EDIT/ANSWER: this works fine in mongoose >= 3.0 also**

I have a mongoose schema that looks like so:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId

VehicleSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  make: String
  model: String
  year: Number
  body: String
  fuel: String
  transmission: String
  parts: [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Part' } ]

VehicleSchema.virtual('display_name').get ->
  return this.make + ' ' + this.model + ' ' + this.year

VehicleModel = mongoose.model 'Vehicle', VehicleSchema

module.exports =
  Schema: VehicleSchema
  Model: VehicleModel
```

I add 'parts' to the vehicle like this:

```
Vehicle.Model.findById id, (err, vehicle) ->
      unless err
        part = new Part.Model {
          ...details
        }
        part.save (err, doc) ->
          unless err
            vehicle.parts.push doc
            vehicle.save()
          else
            console.error err
```

which seems to work:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5027bd4340b00b897a000002"), "body" : "car", "fuel" : "unleaded", "make" : "stackover", "model" : "modelname", "parts" : [ ObjectId("5027bd5140b00b897a000006") ], "transmission" : "manual", "year" : 21212 }
```

but when I try and populate the parts:

```
Vehicle.Model
  .findById(vehicle_id)
  .populate('parts')
  .exec (err, doc) ->
    if err
      console.error err
    else
      console.error doc
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Property 'model' of object { parts: [] } is not a function at model.populate [as _populate]
```

What gives? I had another model/controller combination that was almost a carbon copy of this that worked perfectly (I've pretty much find/replaced the nouns and it still breaks, seriously freaking out here!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its likely that the name "model" is used internally, and the definition of VehicleSchema is clobbering something that mongoose expects to be a function with the "String" type.

Comment: this was exactly it, changed `model: String` to `car_model: String` and everything works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `parts` in the schema looks off.  Shouldn't `refs` be `ref:`?

```
parts: [ { type: ObjectId, ref: "Part" } ]
```

Comment: Is the `'Part'` model and schema fully defined prior to the definition  of `VehicleSchema`?

Comment: yeah, even if i define the schemas in my server entry file and pass them to my controllers the same error happens

Comment: that is to say that yes, i defined the part model, console.err'd it out to check it was created, then made the vehicle one and err'd that as well and everything was created in order and on time